# Retrieving specific tweets of a user

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to scrape tweets from a specified user based on a specific keyword using Tweepy. I tried using

`if api.search(q="$"):`

but I am running into an error. How can I solve this problem?

```
#Import the libraries 
import tweepy 

api_key = ""
api_key_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth_handler = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_key_secret)
auth_handler.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth_handler,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user = api.get_user("TheShual")
print("User details:")
print(user.name)
print(user.description)
print(user.location)

userID = "TheShual"

tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=userID, 
                           # 200 is the maximum allowed count
                           count=20,
                           include_rts = False,
                           # Necessary to keep full_text 
                           # otherwise only the first 140 words are extracted
                           tweet_mode = 'extended'
                           )

for info in tweets[:10]:
    if api.search(q="$"):     
        print(info.created_at)
        print(info.full_text)
        print("\n")
```

Comment: Please list your error, or (and) a stacktrace

Comment: [{'code': 195, 'message': 'Missing or invalid url parameter.'}]

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use the cashtag query `$` without a value. Try something like `$twtr`, as described [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query)

Comment: How about a hash? Actually, I want to extract every single tweet where this a # or $, so $twtr is too specific

Comment: This is not achievable in Twitter API, since # and $ are reserved operations for hashtag and cashtag respectively. You can, however, use the following query: `has:hashtags OR has:cashtags`, which will bring all tweets having those, and, by implication, having `$` or `#` in their text